# Flutter: Firebase animated list in custom scrollview

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I'm currently using `FirebaseAnimatedList` in my app to show data from firebase. But also I wanted to animate my appbar so I want to use `SliverAppBar`. But the problem is how should I use `FirebaseAnimatedList` in `CustomScrollView` in flutter?